# How place pivot header bottom?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I think, in UWP should be possible to place pivot header to bottom. I read, we can do this without template editing. I cannot find any example.

Thanks for answer

EDIT:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997788.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Header placement.   Headers can be placed at the top or the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you, default behavior like picture bellow
[image]

So, just use this Style for `Pivot`

```
    <Style x:Key="PivotHeaderBottomStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                            <Style x:Key="TitleContentControlStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontFamily}"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleThemeFontWeight}"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontSize}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisibility">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsHidden"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Header">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="StaticHeader">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                        IsTabStop="False" 
                                        Margin="{StaticResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TitleContentControlStyle}"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                          BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"
                                          HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}"
                                          VerticalSnapPointsType="None"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                          VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                          ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform"/>
                                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="LeftHeaderPresenter"
                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LeftHeaderTemplate}"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding LeftHeader}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper"
                                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                        UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
                                            <ContentControl.Clip>
                                                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry"/>
                                            </ContentControl.Clip>
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                        <TransformGroup>
                                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform"/>
                                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform"/>
                                                        </TransformGroup>
                                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                        <Button x:Name="PreviousButton"
                                                Background="Transparent"
                                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                Height="36" IsTabStop="False" 
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                IsEnabled="False"
                                                Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" 
                                                Opacity="0"
                                                Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}" 
                                                UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                                Width="20"/>
                                        <Button x:Name="NextButton"
                                                Background="Transparent"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                Height="36"
                                                IsTabStop="False"
                                                IsEnabled="False"
                                                Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}"
                                                Opacity="0"
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                Template="{StaticResource NextTemplate}"
                                                UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                Width="20"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter"
                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}"
                                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter"
                                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                                        Grid.Row="0">
                                            <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform"/>
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        </ItemsPresenter>
                                    </Grid>
                                </PivotPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and your `Pivot` will be like this

[image]

Comment: It's not working with Xamarin.Forms it shows only the page names

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Pivot class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx) there isn't any property to move the pivot header to the bottom, so the example that you found is just a hint to how to use a pivot properly.

But at the end you need to edit the template.

Comment: Ok thank you, for your answer. Unfortunately, I will have to edit the template :(

Comment: i have tried some stuff, none of them worked. Edit the template it's not hard especially if you use blend ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @Andrii Krupka style to get it work on Xamarin.Forms UWP:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/430469/#Comment_430469

[image]