# Tab icons in a Xamarin.Forms UWP TabbedPage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp, tabbedpage

When putting together a **TabbedPage** in Xamarin.Forms, how do I get UWP to use the page's **Icon** property?

It [looks like UWP could support this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot) just fine, if I configure my Forms attributes/files correctly.

Here's my TabbedPage XAML. The icons are all set up and working for iOS and Android, and even the on-page Image in UWP renders fine (meaning the files are likely in the project correctly).

```xml
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tabbed"
             x:Class="tabbed.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:InitialPage Title="Tab1" Icon="star.png" />
        <ContentPage Title="Tab2" Icon="gear.png">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="A nice label." />
                    <Image Source="star.png" /><!-- works here -->
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is currently, the [UWP TabbedPage renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/19c53765c6a0580831337777cc64f832e1c98ed3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/TabbedPageRenderer.cs) does not use the Icon property at all, so getting tab icons will require a custom renderer. Even the official UWP samples don't actually seem to have this baked-in, [requiring a custom UserControl](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlPivot/cs/TabHeader.xaml).

The [Android **TabbedPageRenderer**](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/19c53765c6a0580831337777cc64f832e1c98ed3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs#L377-L394) and [iOS **TabbedRenderer**](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/19c53765c6a0580831337777cc64f832e1c98ed3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabbedRenderer.cs#L388-L402), and even the [macOS **TabbedPageRenderer**](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/19c53765c6a0580831337777cc64f832e1c98ed3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS/Renderers/TabbedPageRenderer.cs#L200-L209), use the Icon property to adjust the tab UI, but the UWP renderer would need updating to make this work.

Comment: Agreed, thank you. I have to wait another hour to do so, though.

Answer (score 4):

I outlined how this is possible here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/07/12/xamarin-forms-tabbed-page-uwp-with-images/

In short, you need to change the default `HeaderTemplate` that is being used by UWP. But due to the way Xamarin forms is started, this is not straightforward.
So you need to inject a custom template into the resource dictionary.

Example project is up on Github here https://github.com/Depechie/XamarinFormsTabbedPageUWPWithIcons

Longer detail:

You need to supply your own `TabbedPageStyle` and switch out the one that Xamarin is using for their UWP rendering.
So the new style contains an Image where we data bind the Source to the Xamarin Icon property.

```
<Style x:Key="TabbedPageStyle2" TargetType="uwp:FormsPivot">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" Width="15" Height="15" />
                    <TextBlock Name="TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock" Text="{Binding Title}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The actual style switching is done in the `App.Xaml.cs` like this

```
((Style)this.Resources["TabbedPageStyle"]).Setters[0] = ((Style)this.Resources["TabbedPageStyle2"]).Setters[0];
```

You'll also need a converter to be sure the Image control understands the Icon source giving by Xamarin

```
public class IconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && value is Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)
            return ((Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)value).File;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [provide some more relevant details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from your external link directly in the answer?

Comment: Looks like icons now work in the latest UWP implementations, but not a lot of control is given to the layout. I think using a Style replacement is the key - for example, do you know how to move the Tabs to the bottom using this technique?

Comment: To be honest I haven't looked at the new implementation. I guess you first need to figure out what control is being used in the UWP target. With that maybe you can find a way to change the layout... like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482341/how-place-pivot-header-bottom if it would be a pivot contol.